# apt-get wont update because of broken package mysql-server-core-5.1

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

here are the messages i get when I try to force install:

```
zack@HAL9000:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  mysql-server: Depends: mysql-server-5.1 but it is not going to be installed
  mysql-server-core-5.1: Depends: libmysqlclient16 (>= 5.1.41-3ubunt�12.3) but 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.3 is to be installed
                         Depends: libstdc+k6 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
zack@HAL9000:~$ dpkg -L mysql-server-5.1
dpkg-query: parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 44946 package 'mysql-server-core-5.1':
 `Conflicts' field, invalid package name `
zack@HAL9000:~$ cd /var/cache/apt/archives
zack@HAL9000:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-server-core-5.1_5.1.41-3ubuntu12.3_i386.deb
dpkg: parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 44946 package 'mysql-server-core-5.1':
 `Conflicts' field, invalid package name `
```

any ideas on how to get this fixed?

Comment: Did you already try apt-get update before this installation? There was recently an update to MySQL on Ubuntu.

Comment: yes, the invalid package name stops everything. no matter what I do I get:  dpkg-query: parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 44946 package 'mysql-server-core-5.1':
 `Conflicts' field, invalid package name `

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when mixing repos in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: Not mixing distributions in sources.list. I don't know if it was your case...  

  

$ man sources.list

Comment: BTW, look the line 44946 of /var/lib/dpkg/status, maybe is corrupted and you can fix it there. The disk have space left, doesn't it?

Comment: about 23 gigs...thanks, you jarred some memory...to fix it it was:

sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status